# Dynamic text Fields and comboboxes creation

Tags: java, mysql

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
        initComponents(); // Netbeans defined function non-editable    
        setTitle("Adding and Removing Components Dynamically From a JPanel in Java");
        combo1_combo2_text1_array(); // declaring array for new row addition
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

    private javax.swing.JComboBox[] combo1; //array of JComboBoxes
    private javax.swing.JComboBox[] combo2; //array of JComboBoxes
    private javax.swing.JTextField[] text1; //array of JTextFields
    private int count = -1; 
    private int max_row = 10;
    private int empty_count = 0;  

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        removerow = new javax.swing.JButton();
        addrow = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        jComboBox2 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        reset = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        removerow.setText("removerow");
        removerow.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                removerowActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        addrow.setText("addrow");
        addrow.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                addrowActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });                  

    private void removerowActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
         if(count > -1){ // Deleting one row at a time
            jPanel2.remove(combo1[count]);
            jPanel2.remove(combo2[count]);
            jPanel2.remove(text1[count]);
            count--;
            jPanel2.revalidate();
            jPanel2.repaint();
        }
    }                                         

    private void addrowActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
         if(count == max_row-1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Maximum of 10 rows can be added","Failed!!",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }
        count++;        
        combo1[count] = new javax.swing.JComboBox(); 
        for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){
            combo1[count].addItem("Item " + i);
        }       
        combo2[count] = new javax.swing.JComboBox(); 
        for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){
            combo2[count].addItem("Item " + i);
        }   
        text1[count] = new javax.swing.JTextField();        
        jPanel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,3,20,20));
        jPanel2.add(combo1[count]);
        jPanel2.add(combo2[count]);
        jPanel2.add(text1[count]);
        jPanel2.revalidate();
        jPanel2.repaint();

    }                                      

    private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                          

    private void jComboBox2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                          

    private void resetActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        jTextField1.setText("");
        for(int i=count;i>-1;i--){
            jPanel2.remove(combo1[i]);
            jPanel2.remove(combo2[i]);
            jPanel2.remove(text1[i]);
            jPanel2.revalidate();
            jPanel2.repaint();
        }
        count = -1;
    }                                     
    private void combo1_combo2_text1_array(){
        combo1 = new JComboBox[10];
        combo2 = new JComboBox[10];
        text1 = new JTextField[10];        
    }

    private void cancelActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {   // Cancel Button Action                                     
        System.exit(0);
    }                                 

   private void submitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        if(jTextField1.getText().length()==0)  // Submit button for the register form
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Empty fields detected ! Please fill up all fields","Failed!!",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);      
        else if(count > -1){            
            for(int i=0;i<=count;i++){
                if(text1[count].getText().length()==0)  
                    empty_count++;                
            }
            if(empty_count > 0){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Empty fields detected ! Please fill up all fields","Failed!!",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
                empty_count = 0; // resetting the count
            }
            else
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No database connection for this application","Failed!!",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No database connection for this application","Failed!!",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);        
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {


        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton addrow;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox1;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JButton removerow;
    private javax.swing.JButton reset;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

This is the code i used. when adding rows it should add a row. It works but not adding those in a proper order.how can i correct that. i think there's a problem with panels. i can't find the fault.
I want to add fields when clicking add rows button and deleting when clicking delete rows button. Deleting process is working good. but adding is not.

http://www.lionblogger.com/adding-and-removing-components-dynamically-from-jpanel/ this is where i got this code. can some one tell me where do i add these buttons and feilds? to which jpanel? In a one Jpanel or in two panels?

Can i use date pickers instead of text fields?

Comment: What do you mean my *not adding those in a proper order*?

Comment: Ok it's done by myself. can i increase the space between two fields?

Comment: You can increase space between two fields if you put fields to different cells in GridLayout and GridLayout is created with gaps specified (by using constructor `GridLayout(int rows, int cols, int hgap, int vgap)`.  In your code you specified 20 as a hgap (see `jPanel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,3,20,20));`).

Comment: Can i use date pickers instead of text fields?